# Undefined index: log in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\home.php on line 20

Tags: php

```
18 <?php
19 include("session/DBConnection.php");
20 $user = $_SESSION['log']['username'];
21 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user'"); 
22 $display = mysql_fetch_array($query);    ?>
23 <title>sagar- <?php echo $display['firstname'] . " " . $display['lastname']    ?>       23</title>
```

please help me out...i am so confused...show me ans in code ....what should i have to write....please guys help me..!!

Comment: make sure you started  the session; session_start();

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if that array key has been set before using it.

```
$user = isset($_SESSION['log']) and isset($_SESSION['log']['username'])
    ? $_SESSION['log']['username']
    : '';
```

Comment: Minor point, you only need to check `isset($_SESSION['log']['username'])` in this instance.